# Coordinates of known black holes in our Galaxy (Milky Way)

Tags: black-hole, galaxy, milky-way, coordinate

There are some articles in wikipedia with the list of known (or candidates) black holes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_black_holes) and [list of nearest black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_black_holes). Also there is a [map of Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way#/media/File:Artist%27s_impression_of_the_Milky_Way_(updated_-_annotated).jpg).

My question is where can I get approximate position of the known black holes in our Galaxy (Milky Way) as [Galactic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system) or maybe some other galaxy coordinates?

Comment: Do you mean positions in 3d? Or just positions in the sky in 2d Galactic coordinates?

Comment: If it's just 2D Galactic coordinates, then you can look up the objects on Simbad. (In fact, each of the objects in the second Wikipedia list has, on its own Wikipedia page, a link to the corresponding Simbad page (right-hand sidebar, under "Database references".)

Comment: I got one: 0.0.0  and it's big.

Comment: @RobJeffries I am not sure. Which coordinates are most used for galaxy objects?

Comment: The 2D galactic coordinates can be straightforwardly obtained from Simbad (as described by Peter Erwin) or by taking the RA, Dec and converting them into galactic coordinates http://www.robertmartinayers.org/tools/coordinates.html

Comment: 3d positions is more interesting, but difficult, since an accurate distance to most of these objects is unknown. That will all change next month when Gaia-DR2 is released.

Comment: Related: Phil Plait (BadAstronomy) posted that soon (i.e days or weeks or something) astronomers will be observing a star plunging very close to a nearby black hole - it won't be captured, but things might be interesting.

Comment: How to understand SIMBAD database? For example for this one
http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=1A%200620-00

Is it this line related to galactic coordinates?
"Gal coord. (ep=J2000) : 209.9563 -06.5399 [ 100 12 0 ]"
as I understand 2D galactic coordinates is a angle from 0 to 360 and distance in light years. where is it in this database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I go from the [list of black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_black_holes) to the page of a particular object like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A0620-00) there is a link to SIMBAD database like [this](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=1A%200620-00). This SIMBAD database has galactic coordinates in this format

Gal coord. (ep=J2000) : 209.9563 -06.5399 [ 100 12 0 ]

where 209.9563 is a Galactic longitude, which changes from 0 to 360 degrees. -06.5399 is Galactic latitude, which is always around zero (+/- 10 degrees), because our galaxy is almost flat. Good explanation for galactic coordinates is on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system).

To put the object on 2D map like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system#/media/File:Artist%27s_impression_of_the_Milky_Way_(updated_-_annotated).jpg) only Galactic longitude and distance to the object is needed. For example, this is the map of all black holes which I could find in wikipedia in our Galaxy.

[image]

Comment: That map cannot be produced using just Galactic latitude and longitude.